# Snap Svg Bounding Box and Transform Coordinates

Tags: coordinates, transform, bounding-box, snap.svg

I can't figure how to place a path relative to its sibling path's bounding box. Imagine a box like a window and I want to put a close button to the top right corner of it. Here is the box and close button grouped together after transforming the window (scaling it 3x):

```
<g id="group24">
        <path id="path24" fill="#00aa00" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M301,585.08v47h45.834l-0.134-21.8
            l12.3-0.2l-1-239H253v216c0,0,22,0.2,22,0c0-41,26-31.357,26-31.357V585.08L301,585.08z" transform="matrix(3,0,0,3,-612,-1003.16)"></path>

<path id="close-button" fill="#B40000" d="M256,232c-13.255,0-24,10.745-24,24s10.745,24,24,24s24-10.745,24-24
    S269.255,232,256,232z M265.102,270.277l-8.985-8.984l-8.985,8.985l-4.826-4.829l8.983-8.984l-8.984-8.984l4.829-4.826l8.983,8.982
    l8.981-8.983l4.83,4.827l-8.983,8.983l8.984,8.983L265.102,270.277z"></path>
</g>
```

I just append the button after transforming the box (animate callback) to the group24 group dynamically and close button appears like this:

[image: Close button appears not in top left of group24]

And after when I get the bounding box of the path24 element in group and try to position the close button to the top right:

```
var p = this.SvgButton.select("path");
var bbox = myBox.getBBox();
var coordString = (bbox.x2 - 10) + " " + (bbox.y);
p.transform("T" + coordString);
```

the coordinates are always wrong. How can I position the close button to the top right corner of the lightgreen box?

**An example of what I'm trying to achieve is here: http://jsfiddle.net/savpm8w3/1/**
Note that scale animation doesn't work in jsfiddle and thats why the example in fiddle works.

Comment: Is it possible to put up a basic jsfiddle showing it ?

Comment: Hello I've added an example jsfiddle, what I try to achieve works (without transforms) here: http://jsfiddle.net/savpm8w3/1/. For some reason scale animation doesn't work in jsfiddle. I want to achieve this with a 3x scaled transformed main box (rect1) after the animation ends.

Comment: You may want to output the matrix you have created, see if it is what you think it is. Out of interest, try getBBox(1) as well just to see if it makes any difference, iirc there was something like if its 1 it will take into account transformations (I may be wrong though!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue by adding a plugin to Snap.Svg which positions elements relative to other Snap objects' bounding boxes. It can be further worked on to provide more transformation types. If anyone's interested here is the code:

```
    Snap.plugin( function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {
    Element.prototype.getCenter = function() {
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        return {x: bbox.cx, y:bbox.cy};
    };
    Element.prototype.getSize = function() {
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        return {w: bbox.width, h:bbox.height};
    };
    Element.prototype.getPos = function() {
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        return {x: bbox.x, y:bbox.y};
    };
    Element.prototype.getTransformRelative = function(relativeObj, type, absolute, xadjust, yadjust) {
        var movex = 0;
        var movey = 0;
        switch (type) {
            case "center":
                var c = relativeObj.getCenter();
                var elpos = this.getPos();
                var elsize = this.getSize();
                var movex = c.x - (elsize.w / 2);
                var movey = c.y - (elsize.h / 2);

                movex = (elpos.x > movex ? 0 - (elpos.x - movex) : movex - elpos.x);
                movey = (elpos.y > movey ? 0 - (elpos.y - movey) : movey - elpos.y);
                break;
            case "topleft":
                var movepos = relativeObj.getPos();
                var elpos = this.getPos();

                movex = (elpos.x > movepos.x ? 0 - (elpos.x - movepos.x) : movepos.x - elpos.x);
                movey = (elpos.y > movepos.y ? 0 - (elpos.y - movepos.y) : movepos.y - elpos.y);
                break;
            case "bottomleft":
                var movepos = relativeObj.getBBox();
                var elpos = this.getPos();

                movex = (elpos.x > movepos.x ? 0 - (elpos.x - movepos.x) : movepos.x - elpos.x);
                movey = (elpos.y > movepos.y2 ? 0 - (elpos.y - movepos.y2) : movepos.y2 - elpos.y);
                break;
            case "topright":
                var movepos = relativeObj.getPos();
                var rsize = relativeObj.getSize();
                var elsize = this.getSize();
                var elpos = this.getPos();

                movex = (elpos.x > movepos.x ? 0 - (elpos.x - movepos.x) : movepos.x - elpos.x);
                movey = (elpos.y > movepos.y ? 0 - (elpos.y - movepos.y) : movepos.y - elpos.y);
                movex += rsize.w - elsize.w;
                break;
            case "bottomright":
                var movepos = relativeObj.getBBox();
                var rsize = relativeObj.getSize();
                var elsize = this.getSize();
                var elpos = this.getPos();

                movex = (elpos.x > movepos.x2 ? 0 - (elpos.x - movepos.x2) : movepos.x2 - elpos.x);
                movey = (elpos.y > movepos.y2 ? 0 - (elpos.y - movepos.y2) : movepos.y2 - elpos.y);
                break;
            case "topcenter":
                var c = relativeObj.getCenter();
                var rpos = relativeObj.getPos();
                var elpos = this.getPos();
                var elsize = this.getSize();
                var movex = c.x - (elsize.w / 2);

                movex = (elpos.x > movex ? 0 - (elpos.x - movex) : movex - elpos.x);
                movey = (elpos.y > rpos.y ? 0 - (elpos.y - rpos.y) : rpos.y - elpos.y);
                break;
            case "bottomcenter":
                var c = relativeObj.getCenter();
                var rpos = relativeObj.getBBox();
                var elpos = this.getPos();
                var elsize = this.getSize();
                var movex = c.x - (elsize.w / 2);

                movex = (elpos.x > movex ? 0 - (elpos.x - movex) : movex - elpos.x);
                movey = (elpos.y > rpos.y2 ? 0 - (elpos.y - rpos.y2) : rpos.y2 - elpos.y);
                break;
            case "leftcenter":
                var c = relativeObj.getCenter();
                var rpos = relativeObj.getPos();
                var elpos = this.getPos();
                var elsize = this.getSize();
                var movey = c.y - (elsize.h / 2);

                movex = (elpos.x > rpos.x ? 0 - (elpos.x - rpos.x) : rpos.x - elpos.x);
                movey = (elpos.y > movey ? 0 - (elpos.y - movey) : movey - elpos.y);
                break;
            case "rightcenter":
                var c = relativeObj.getCenter();
                var rbox = relativeObj.getBBox();
                var elpos = this.getPos();
                var elsize = this.getSize();
                var movey = c.y - (elsize.h / 2);

                movex = (elpos.x > rbox.x2 ? 0 - (elpos.x - rbox.x2) : rbox.x2 - elpos.x);
                movey = (elpos.y > movey ? 0 - (elpos.y - movey) : movey - elpos.y);
                break;
            default:
                console.log("ERROR: Unknown transform type in getTransformRelative!");
                break;
        }

        if (typeof(xadjust) === 'undefined') xadjust = 0;
        if (typeof(yadjust) === 'undefined') yadjust = 0;
        movex = movex + xadjust;
        movey = movey + yadjust;

        return (absolute ? "T"+movex+","+movey : "t"+movex+","+movey);
    };
});
```